# Resolving port issue of node js application and windows server

Tags: node.js, iis

**Introduction :**
My windows server is listening at port 3000.When i start my node application to use port 3000 for listening, it failed with error.

I understand that i have alternate method of deploying node app using iis but i failed.The only way left is making problem i.e "port".

**Edit**
When i unbind the port, i app start working.

If someone have better idea or idea about this problem, please do help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you add your error please ?

Comment: I was working remotely, i lost connection, error was same as saying "this is the problem with kurento not npm"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one server at a time can use a given port.  If your windows server is already using port 3000, then you can't start another server on that same port.  You will have to either stop the first server or pick a different port number.

Or, use some sort of proxy as your only listener on port 3000 and have it divide the traffic among your two servers which would each run on different ports.

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan - There are good reasons to use a proxy.  You have not describe enough about your situation for us to know if you need one or not or whether you should just pick different port numbers or whether you should just stop the other server.  All are reasonable solutions given the appropriate situation.  Running a proxy is the more complicated solution so I'd recommend one of the other options unless there's a really good reason you can't pick one of the other options.